# navigator.share api in android changes the name of the file that the user shares

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-android

I create a .csv file to download it. In windows everything works fine, but in android, when sharing the file it is downloaded with a different name like "share9457849389.csv"

```js
const file = new File([text], 'myFile.csv', {
  type: 'text/csv'
})

if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({
    files: [file]
  })) {
  navigator
    .share({
      files: [file],
      text: 'Some text',
      title: `The title`
    })
    .then(() => resolve(''))
    .catch((e: any) => reject(e))
} else reject('Bad news')
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73716328/1973735

Comment: Same issue happening with me, please share if someone finds any solution.