# Why web share API converts file name in random?

Tags: javascript, api, share, sharing

Implementing simple and default web share `API` level 2 code for files, `API` changes the file name to random.

Just in case I will show here my  code of sharing file with `API`. I said "just in case" because the same occurs to me in official chromestatus site and other sample sites.

```
async function enviar_gmail(){

const title = document.getElementById('subject').value;
const text = document.getElementById('body-big').value;

const response = await fetch('assets/img/hello.pdf');
const blob = await response.blob();
const filesArray = [new File([blob],'hello.pdf',{type: "application/pdf", lastModified: new Date().getTime()})];

if (!navigator.canShare || !navigator.canShare({files: filesArray})) {
        
$('.notification').html('No se accepta');
$('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
        
return false;
}

const shareData = {

title: title,
text: text,
files: filesArray,
};

if (navigator.canShare && !navigator.canShare(shareData)) {
              
$('.notification').html('No se accepta');
     $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
     
      return false;
  }

navigator.share(shareData);

}
```

Works good except it shows `share635287463528173875.pdf` as attached file, not `hello.pdf`.
Doesn´t matter if it is `.jpg` or `.txt`.

The same occurs with sharing local input file!

And finally I went to official web share `API` site and examples which confirmed it:

[Crome Platform Status](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4777349178458112)

All links showed random file name of any kind of accepted file types (`.txt`, `.pdf`, `.jpg`) eg.`share365645756784578.jpg` etc.

So I asked first, is it possible that I am the only one in this world having this problem (which make this API useless) because nobody reports this except one post without solution: [HERE](https://github.com/w3c/web-share/issues/201)

Is it related with my location, Spain, which has no sense but I ask just in case because I am sure it is a BUG because the same error occurs in all test sites I found (see above)?

Tested on mobile chrome `V96`; `Android 11`.

If someone can tell me what is going on here with this `API` and file names.
I was waiting 2 years for Google to finally implements `.pdf` as accepted file and that my client can share invoice pdf attachment, but no way.

I forgot to say, I tried the same on my wife´s and friend´s mobiles and it shows the same random filename.

Is it a any workaround for this, because obviously all codes I tried are good.
This community is the last chance for me, like now, `API` is useless.

I am not able to hack and write java in Chromium, it is supposed to be a job of trillion dollar worth company who made it, so my opinion is, if **stackoverflow** community can´t help, nobody can do it, so I will report it as a bug.

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

The `web-share` specification allows the supplied name to be used while sharing. However, implementation in chrome somewhat differed up until chromium version [98.0.4740.1](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/98.0.4740.1/chrome/browser/webshare/chromeos/sharesheet_client.cc#L52). A [change](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/175301b99ad6800922dd3b201fb53530509ad480) was pushed in Dec, 2021 which **preserves filename if possible**. This change is live in version 98.0.4741.0 and beyond.

A [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96f4cnt5/1/) which works in the expected way in chrome iOS version 105.0.5195.100.

Comment: Since browsers may re-encode certain files, for example, to remove Exif metadata or to make sure images contain no "compression bomb" attacks, the file name is not necessarily preserved. The [spec validation section](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/#validate-share-data) in fact includes no requirement to preserve the file name. That being said, keeping the name obviously is still behavior most users would expect, which is why I have filed a [bug](https://crbug.com/1340850) for file names to be preserved whenever possible.