# File shared using Web Share API automatically changes its name

Tags: javascript, navigator, web-share

I just learnt the Web Share API and decided to create a file and share it using the navigator.share().
So I created a files called "sample.txt" by this following code-

```js
const parts = [
  new Blob(['you construct a file...'], {
   type: 'text/plain'
  })
];

const file = new File(parts, 'sample.txt', {
  lastModified: new Date(),
  type: "text/plain"
});
```

And passed it to the navigator.share function as a property called "files" of an object

```js
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
    title: "Good",
    files: [file]
  })
}
```

It worked, I could share it in WhatsApp but the name of the file changes to share409662553725258186628...

How can It be shared using the same navigator.share along with retaining it's original name "sample.txt"

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73716328/1973735