# Why do Web Share shared files end up with a random name?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, web-share

I'm using the navigator.share feature to share a PDF generated with [jspdf](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF). So far everything is working fine: the file is generated correctly with all the desired contents and it can be shared/downloaded without any major issue. The problem is that the document's name is being changed to a random name, always in the form of "share"+bunchOfNumbers+".pdf", ignoring the defined name on the File creation.

The only posts I've found regarding this issue are [Why web share API converts file name in random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494648/why-web-share-api-converts-file-name-in-random) and [navigator.share api in android changes the name of the file that the user shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483947/navigator-share-api-in-android-changes-the-name-of-the-file-that-the-user-shares), and also [this](https://github.com/w3c/web-share/issues/201) already closed bug, but none of them got any answer/resolution.

Here is my code to share the file:

```js
if (navigator.canShare && navigator.userAgentData.mobile) {
  var pdf = new File([doc.output('blob')], doc_name + ".pdf", { type: "application/pdf" });
  var filesToShare = [pdf];

  try {
    navigator.share({ title: doc_name + ".pdf", files: filesToShare });
  } catch (error) {
    showBanner(error.message, bannerState.ERROR, ALERT_PARENT, ALERT_TIME);
  }
}
```

But I end up with this:

The name is correct on the title

[image]

But the pdf has a random name:

[image]

Any kind of help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more of an Android bug (or maybe intended behavior?) and not a problem with your code. I have reported this as a bug, so feel free to star to be notified of progress: https://crbug.com/1340850.

Comment: Thanks for raising this at the correct forum.